# Return values for service tier functions

Tags: architecture

I'm developing an application and I'm using a "service" tier between my controllers and repositories to perform model/business validations.  Since this is a multi-tenant application (with shared database) I need to perform permission validations on all operations.

One thing that I'm unsure how to handle is return types in case a user has no access to a specific operation.  For example, say I have a method `GetAccountById`.  Normally this method would return an instance of an `Account` entity (or `null` if one doesn't exist).  What would the appropriate return value be in case where the account does exist, but the current user doesn't have access to it?  I don't really want to throw an exception, as it doesn't seem like a good use for one.  So the question is: how do I alert the consumer of my service tier (be it a controller or a web service) that the authorization is not valid?  Should I just create some kind of a `GetAccountByIdResult` type and include the outcome of the function in there (including any "error" codes, actual entity etc.)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what I do in my service layer is actually always include a "result" object which contains an error bool, a collection of error messages (which you can read if `Error` is true) ... and then the actual object/resource

```
{
  error:true,
  messages: ['error1','error2'],
  value: { name:'blah' }
}
```

Comment: Do you have one generic "result" object or many depending on the method?

Comment: it depends on the technologies involved ... I usually try to have a generic result object. when accessing rest/json services from javascript, makes it really easy since json is dynamically typed. if the client is a statically typed language (java, c#, etc.) then I will either have a generic one with an 'object' value, or a strongly typed value if the situation necessitates it. Usually, if I'm the author of the client, I'll use object since it's easy enough for me to cast the result. However, if I'm writing for other consumers, I usually strongly type

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind I've never actually had to do this (that I can remember)...
I guess it depends on where you enforce authorization.

- If you enforce it at the service level then you'd define it there;  I guess you could have a generic 'fault' response and/or specific ones for specific services.
- If you enforce it at the repository level then that would return whatever it wanted to, and your service layer would have to handle that and figure out what to return - which brings us back to the first point.